# Volume of a circle $x^2 +y^2 \leq 1$ which is revolving around a line $x+y=2$.

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, applications, solid-of-revolution

I want to compute the volume of a circle $x^2 +y^2 \leq 1$ which is revolving around a line $x+y=2$. Usually I solved problems about solids revolving around axis and non axis horizontal and vertical lines. But it seems to have neither horizontal nor vertical line. So I find it difficult for me to understand how can I solve this.

Can I get any help for this?

Comment: The line is at $\sqrt 2$ distance from the center of the circle. Any line at that distance from the center will give the same volume. So you can do it for line $x = \sqrt2$ or $y = \sqrt2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a change of coordinates. Rotate the graph $45^\circ$ (and redraw the axes) to obtain this equivalent problem: find the volume of the solid obtained by revolving the circle $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$ about the line $y = \sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Pappus theorem,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem) the volume of revolution is $2 \pi d A$, where $d$ is the distance from the centroid of the region to the axis of rotation and $A$ is the area bounded by the region.  The centroid of the region is $(0,0)$ and the distance to the line $x+y-2=0$ is $\frac{|0+0-2|}{\sqrt{1^2+1^2}}=\sqrt{2}$, and $A$ is $\pi$.  Therefore, the volume of revolution is $2\pi \sqrt{2} \pi$ or $\boxed{2\sqrt{2} \pi^2}$.